# Exception at android.app.ActivityThread.handleTrimMemory

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception

I am new to Android development and maintaining an Android App code. We just got an exception as follow:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.contracts.shared.JsonHelper.a(JsonHelper.java:239)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.contracts.shared.JsonHelper.writeDictionary(JsonHelper.java:175)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.contracts.EventData.serializeContent(EventData.java:143)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.contracts.Domain.serialize(Domain.java:53)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.contracts.shared.JsonHelper.writeJsonSerializable(JsonHelper.java:149)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.contracts.Data.serializeContent(Data.java:54)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.contracts.Base.serialize(Base.java:59)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.contracts.shared.JsonHelper.writeJsonSerializable(JsonHelper.java:149)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.contracts.Envelope.serializeContent(Envelope.java:436)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.contracts.Envelope.serialize(Envelope.java:330)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.library.g.a(Persistence.java:118)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.library.b.a(ChannelQueue.java:138)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.library.b.a(ChannelQueue.java:116)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.library.a.b(Channel.java:74)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.library.f.onTrimMemory(LifeCycleTracking.java:292)
    at android.app.Application.onTrimMemory(Application.java:152)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleTrimMemory(ActivityThread.java:4920)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

The Android BUILD_VERSION_SDK_INT is 21.

Would you please give me some hints on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to post your relevant code where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Look like it's being thrown by Android system code. I am new to Android development, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're right, this doesn't look like your own code. Ignore me...